# Force.com Migration Tool "Validate Only" causing later compilation errors

Tags: visualforce, ant, migration-tool, jenkins

We just implemented a new process in our development cycle where code that has been completed is validated against a target org to check that no packaging specific rules have been violated (such as changing the method signature of a global method). After running several different validates (using `checkOnly="true"` on our `sf:deploy` target) we are getting a very odd issue where it seems the compiler thinks some of the validated code now exists in some Visualforce.

An example of this is the error:

> pages/MyPage.page -- Error: Unknown property 'Namespace.MyPageCtrl.newProperty'

This `newProperty` member variable is in one of the new feature branches that was validated against the org, but was not deployed and is not being referenced in the copy of `MyPage.page` that is being deployed right now (the copy being deployed right now is identical to the copy in the org and I can save the page using the org's VF editor).

I know that we can force a recompile of Apex code but is there any way to force a recompilation of Visualforce or any other way to update the behind-the-scenes dependency mappings? Is it just ill-advised to perform multiple validates that include very different code? I was under the impression that validations made zero changes to the org, but this does not really seem to be the case.